# What is the distribution of this product of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a nonnegative integer-valued random variable such that $S_n =\sum_{k=0}^nX^k$ converges in distribution. Then let $T_n =XS_n$. What is the distribution of $T_n$, and, if it exists, of $\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n$?

My motivation for this question came from trying to compute $\mathbb P(X(1+X)=n)$ for a particular $X$. I saw this generalization and was curious if there was a nice closed form.

For $n=$1 I found that the generating function of $X(1+X)$ is  $$G_1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_nz^{n(n+1)},$$ where $p_n = \mathbb P(X=n)$, which generalizes to $$G_n(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n z^{\frac{n(n^{n+1}-1)}{n-1}},
$$
But I don't see a way to get a limit distribution out of this.

For the case where $X\sim\mathrm{Ber(p)}$, we have $$\sum_{k=0}^n X^k \stackrel d= 1 +nX,$$ so $G(z)=1-p+pz^{n+1}$, from which it is clear that $T_n$ converges in distribution to zero. Though I don't see a way to generalize this to an arbitrary distribution.

Comment: $S_n$ cannot converge in distribution unless $X=0$ almost surely.

Comment: Doesn't $T_n$ converge to zero when $X\sim\mathrm{Ber}(p)$?

Comment: I don't undersatdn what you are saying. My claim is that $X=0$ and $T_n=0$ under you assumptions. So the question hardly makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

$S_n$ is an increasing sequence so $\lim S_n=S$ exists almost surely ( $S$ being possibly $\infty$). But if $S_n$ converges in distribution then it will converge almost surely and $S$ has the limiting distribution. Hence your assumptions imply that $\sum X^{n}$ converges almost surely. This implies that $X^{n}\to 0$ almost surely which can happen only when $X=0$ almost surely (since it is integer valued). Hence $T_n=0$ and $lim T_n=0$.

$0 \leq S_n \uparrow $ almost surely and $S_n \to T$ indistribution implies that $S_n$ converges almost surely to a finite limit.

Proof: Let $S =\lim S_n$ (which may be $\infty$). $e^{-S_n} \to e^{-S}$ almost surely. If $S_n \to T$ in distribution then $e^{-S_n } \to e^{-T}$ in distrbution. It follows that $e^{-S}$ has same distribution as $e^{-T}$. This implies that $S <\infty$ almost surely. [There are many other alternative arguments for this].